# Remove “b” and “ac” from a given string

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings

I coded this solution for this problem:

*Given a string, eliminate all “b” and “ac” in the string, you have to replace them in-place, and you are only allowed to iterate over the string once*

Seems to work but I am not sure if I violated the "you are only allowed to iterate over the string once" requirement. Did I?
Other feedback also welcome.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder test  = new StringBuilder("ababac");

        try
        {

        int i=0;
        while( i<test.Length )
        {
            if(test[i] == 'b')
            {
                if(i!=test.Length-1){
                test[i] = test[i+1];
                test.Remove(i+1,1);
                }
                else
                 test.Remove(i,1);

            }else if(i<test.Length -1 && test[i] == 'a' && test[i+1]=='c')
            {

               if(i!=test.Length-2)
               {
                test[i] = test[i+2];
                test[i+1] = test[i+3];
                test.Remove(i+2,1);
                test.Remove(i+2,1);
                }
                else
                {
                 test.Remove(i,1);  
                 test.Remove(i,1);  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        }
        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    }
}
```

Sample

```
In: 

acbac
aababc

Output:

aaac
```

Comment: "You have to replace them in place".  I would argue that dumping it into a StringBuilder and removing characters is functionally equivalent to converting the string to a linked list and removing character nodes, which is *NOT* in-place.  If you are going to do that, it would be cleaner to only copy the valid characters to a new StringBuilder and return it.

Comment: @Zack I had thought that due to using remove I am violating the requirement to iterate only once.

Comment: For the requirement "iterate only once", what you are doing is pretty standard.  It really just means that you get one "pass" over the indexes.  Look ahead/behind is fine.  You are meeting the spirit of that part of the requirement.

Comment: @Zack Hm I thought using remove I violated iterate only once requirement, not the one you mention.

Comment: I would argue that "remove" is fine.  As to my original "in-place" comment, after thinking on it some more it seems to me that the requirement was really designed with c/c++ in mind where strings are really just arrays of characters.  Modern languages, including C#, handle string differently enough that an "in-place" requirement makes little sense and is not practical to try to enforce.

Comment: Should the problem be understood so that the *nested* structures are to be removed, too? Suppose the input is `"qabaccrabct"`, do you need to apply the requirements twice to get `"qacract"` and then `"qrt"`...?

Comment: (@CiaPan: in the 2nd sample string, `abc` just gets transformed to `ac`.)

Comment: @greybeard Thank you. At the first glance I had some trouble to recognize which `a` is which, also which part (if any) of output corresponds to the first string of input. But I think it is quite clear now.

Answer (score 5):

First, realize that in .NET, strings are immutable--it's impossible to actually modify a string "in-place" as asked here. You can do some things that look like modifying a string in place, such as using `+=` on a string--but what that really does is create an entirely new string with the new contents, then modifies the reference to refer to the new contents.

That said, the request is probably pointed toward basically ignoring how things happen under the hood, and writing the code as-if you were able to modify the string. I'd guess the idea they had in mind was to have code that keeps track of two locations (e.g., indices) in the string: a source and a destination.

These initially start out equal (at the beginning of the string). You then walk through the string copying one character at a time from the source location to the destination location (or if the two locations are equal, just advance both without changing anything else). If you get to a character (or group of characters) you're supposed to delete, you just advance the source location without advancing the destination.

Comment: Source and destination point to same memory location? (If you show small sample of what you mean will be easier to follow)

Comment: @user200300: They both start out pointing to the same location (the beginning of the string). When you find something you want to delete, however, you advance the source without advancing the destination, so they no longer point to the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Letting the delete part aside...

I believe you could do better with the *iterate over the string once* part. Everytime you find an *a* you look one char ahead, and then again when it is its turn. You could avoid this by iterating over the string one char at the time and set a flag to true whenever you find an a and in the next iteration remove both if c and in any case set flag to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of removing characters from the string seems a bit obfuscated to me.

Wouldn't the following code work...?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < test.Length;)
    {
        if(test[i] == 'b')
        {
             test.Remove(i,1);
        }
        else if(test[i] == 'a' && i+1 < test.Length && test[i+1] == 'c')
        {
             test.Remove(i,2);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think about `i  == test.Length-1` and `'a'==test[i]`.

Comment: @greybeard Well, if `i == test.Length-1` and `'a'==test[i]` then the middle subexpression `i+1 < test.Length` will return `false` and the third subexpression (comparision to `'c'`) won't be evaluated. The whole condition returns `false` and the control is passed to `else { i++; }` which causes the loop termination on the next `i < test.Length` check. Do I miss something?

Comment: No, I missed the "middle condition/subexpression", the only excuse being I'd never code it like that ;-/

Comment: I considered the `test[i]` a common subexpression of both conditions, so I've put it in front so it could be fetched once, then cached by a compiler in an unnamed temporary variable (possibly a fast CPU register). One could also do it explicitly with some `char c = test[i]; if( c == ...)` or even with `switch(test[i]) {...}` — then of course we don't need checking `i+1<test.Length` if the `i`-th character isn't `'a'`, so I deliberately postponed it until it is necessary, just before accessing the item at position `i+1` .

Comment: @greybeard (Forgot to add a 'ping' in the previous comment, so I do it now.)

Answer (score 0):

## Reference Implementation

Because there has been some interest in a fully compliant implementation, I have created one. This loops over each character once.  There is no look ahead/behind (although I personally think that looking around fits within the spirit of the instructions) and instead I cache the 'a' character when checking for a 'c' on the next pass.  This of course makes the code look a little ugly, as like fizzbuzz, the checks are not quite similar.

This was written and tested in C.

```
void removeTokens(char str[], size_t length)
{
    int ixDst = 0;
    char prevLetter = '\0';
    for(int ixSrc=0; ixSrc<=length; ixSrc++)
    {
        if(prevLetter != '\0' &&  str[ixSrc] != 'c')
        {
            str[ixDst++] = prevLetter;
            prevLetter = '\0';
        }

        switch(str[ixSrc])
        {
            case 'a':
                prevLetter = str[ixSrc];
                break;
            case 'b':
                break;  //no copy
            case 'c':
                if(prevLetter == 'a')
                {
                    prevLetter = '\0';
                    break;  //no copy if prev char was a
                }
                //fallthrough
            default:
                str[ixDst++] = str[ixSrc];
                break;

        }
    }
    str[ixDst] = '\0';
}
```