# Delete all instances of "b" or "ac" from a string

Tags: strings, snobol4

[A recent question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126595/489), inspired me to think about how far we've come, and how much easier tasks are in current, modern languages like C# and Java, compared to the low-level languages we were stuck with years ago.

Based on that, I decided to post some code for doing the same task, but in a language that (at least in most people's estimation) has been obsolete for decades. In this case, I chose an ancient language named SNOBOL 4 for the implementation.

Warning: this really is an old language (this year is its 50<sup>th</sup> anniversary), so try not to be terribly surprised at the length and complexity of the code compared to modern languages like C# and Java.

```
    * read a string from standard input
    input_string = input

* find "b" or "ac" in s, replace with nothing, and repeat if successful:
del_loop input_string ("b" | "ac") =     : s(del_loop)

    * write out resulting string
    output = input_string
```

I don't think anybody's posted any SNOBOL 4 here before, so please be gentle...

Comment: Wow.  That looks very neat.  One question: Are the extra spaces between the `=` and the `:` required?

Comment: @Hosch250: No. I think one space is required, but any more than that is optional.

Comment: OK.  It might look a little better if there was only one space, or if it was on the line below and indented.  Also, why is the indentation so funny, with the top and bottom lines indented more than the middle line?

Comment: @Hosch250: It can't be on the line below. The `del_loop` in the second line is a label, which has to be flush-left. The others don't have labels, so they need to be indented.

Comment: The interesting thing about this code is that it's significantly short, but this is what SNOBOL4 was *designed* for. It was built to be a pattern-matching language, to allow the programmer to manipulate data based on a pattern-oriented approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As best I can tell (with the limited info available on the language), it *looks* like you're violating just a couple language concerns.

First: all example SNOBOL4 code I've seen has the lines without labels indented *past* the horizontal extent of the longest label by at least 2 spaces. That is:

> ```
>     input_string = input
> del_loop input_string ("b" | "ac") =     : s(del_loop)
>     output = input_string
> ```

*Seems* to be expected to be:

```
          input_string = input
del_loop  input_string ("b" | "ac") =     : s(del_loop)
          output = input_string
```

It *also* looks like SNOBOL4 labels are expected to be `SHOUTYLABELS`:

```
         input_string = input
DELLOOP  input_string ("b" | "ac") =     : s(DELLOOP)
         output = input_string
```

The next thing I seem to have seen is that `output`, `input`, and `s` are supposed to be `SHOUTY`.

```
         input_string = INPUT
DELLOOP  input_string ("b" | "ac") =     : S(DELLOOP)
         OUTPUT = input_string
```

The next comment is that it looks like SNOBOL4 code uses `PascalCase` subject (variable) names.

```
         InputString = INPUT
DELLOOP  InputString ("b" | "ac") =     : S(DELLOOP)
         OUTPUT = InputString
```

Next, it looks like the colons should line up vertically and be *past* the last horizontal character on any line. This doesn't apply to you, unless we include your comments:

```
         * read a string from standard input
         InputString = INPUT

* find "b" or "ac" in s, replace with nothing, and repeat if successful:
DELLOOP  InputString ("b" | "ac") =                                       : S(DELLOOP)

         * write out resulting string
         OUTPUT = InputString
```

Lastly, it looks like the transfer is supposed to directly follow the colon. (No spaces.)

```
         InputString = INPUT
DELLOOP  InputString ("b" | "ac") =     :S(DELLOOP)
         OUTPUT = InputString
```

Now, *that* looks like SNOBOL4. :) All-in-all, it looks quite good. Very nice to see an application of a very old language, that shows that *sometimes* the new ones just aren't the best suited for the task. (In fact, SNOBOL4 was designed to fulfill programmes with this in mind, it was *designed* to handle pattern-matching and string-processing **very** well.)